# Does Visual Studio 2008 support configuration (debug/release build) specific references?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, c++-cli, projects-and-solutions

I've got a native C++ project with one C++/CLI file (the only file compiled with /CLI), I'd like to add a reference to a C# DLL.

There are separate versions for debug and release however I can only seem to add one  reference which is applied to all configurations. The reference search path dialog box contains a warning that if I attempt to use any $ConfigurationName type parameters they will only ever refer to the first configuration in the project.

So my current ideas are:

- Join the two projects together under one solution and adding a reference to the "project" rather then the DLL assembly. My understanding is that Visual Studio will then match the configurations. Not ideal as my project and the DLL are "owned" by different areas.
- One project for debug (with only the debug configuration) and a release project (with only a release configuration) but that feels like a bodge.

Any cleaner ways to achieve configuration specific references in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: It doesn't matter, both the debug and the release build of a C# assembly contain the same metadata.  If the C# project is not in your solution then you pick the release build as a reference.  You'll have to stop the practice of renaming the debug build DLLs, that's grossly incompatible with the C# build system.  It only makes sense if you use a linker anyway, you don't link managed code.

Comment: Hi Hans, do you have any links I can learn more about that? I've always used _d as a safeguard against releasing debug builds but also to make to make it clear which DLLs should be used for debugging purposes (ie. the unoptimised ones). Is there an easy to way to tell a debug assembly from a release one if their filenames are identical?

Comment: Yes, the C# build system creates different *folder* names.  bin\Debug and bin\Release.

Comment: As part of using xcopy deployment I often end up with exes and dlls in the same folder, is there an easy to tell the DLLs apart on filename/metadata alone so I can be sure I'm working with the right DLL?

Comment: You only ever copy the release build so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: What if I need to debug into the DLL?

Comment: Then you use the Debug build.  The Release build version of an assembly debugs very well, only thing you miss out on is that you can't set a breakpoint on a curly brace.  Keep in mind that machine code is generated dynamically in .NET, the jitter is aware that a debugger is attached.

Comment: So we need to be mindful of keeping our debug and release builds in separate _folders_ (but the filenames are the same) and then if we need to use a debug build, leave the reference as in and just swap out the release DLL for a debug one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is set the output path for all projects to the same location depending on the configuration. Eg for release builds everything goes into /path/to/Release and for Debug to /path/to Debug. Then I manually edit the project file to include a seperate targets file containing something like this:

**edit** shows how to use conditions to select debug/release dll with a prefix

```
<-- file myDll.targets -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
  <ItemGroup  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Reference Include="myDll_d">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Reference Include="myDll">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then in the project that needs to reference this dll the targets file is included:

```
<Import Project="myDll.targets"/>
```

Because of `Private=false` msbuild won't try to copy anything, it just looks for myDll.dll and will find it in the output path.

This is not particularly clean but does work. The targets file can also be modified to reference different platforms (x86/x64).

Your first idea is probably what is mostly used as it requires the less hassle - except indeed that the projects should be in the same solution (as far as I know);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however our current practice is to append _d to debug dlls and I can't see how to apply your suggestion to address that.

Comment: ha, I actually use that practice as well, but didn't put it into the answer because I tought it was too complicated; I'll add it.

Comment: My vcproj files store references in the form <References><AssemblyReference RelativePath="System.dll" ...  Where could I set the condition here? Based on the msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4sy8216%28v=vs.90%29.aspx, it is not allowed...?

Comment: @TobiasKnauss sorry, no idea.. Did you try it (e.g. `<References Condition="...">` or `<AssemblyReference Condition="..."` ? If that doesn't work you can always ask a new quection.