# Debug and Release versions of the project.

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a  Windows 8 Application that has a dozen of WCF Services that runs in the Cloud (Deployment) and on my Dev machine (Development). I switch a lot between development and deployment and I always have to change the service endpoints everytime I switch. Is there any automated way of doing this? Create a debug and the release version of the project?

Comment: Check if this can help you in any way:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055985/does-visual-studio-2008-support-configuration-debug-release-build-specific-ref

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx