# C++/CLI configuration specific references (debug/release)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, assembly-references

It's almost a duplicate of [Does Visual Studio 2008 support configuration (debug/release build) specific references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7055985/2505186).
I would like to use the answer of this post. The only problem is, I can't, because my `.vcproj` files look very differenty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9,00"
    Name="abcdef"
    ProjectGUID="{41B531B8-2DD7-4C6F-9CE2-85EA79FBAEEF}"
    RootNamespace="abcdef"
    Keyword="ManagedCProj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
    <Platforms>
        <Platform
            Name="Win32"
        />
    </Platforms>
    <ToolFiles>
    </ToolFiles>
    <Configurations>
        <Configuration
            Name="Debug|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
    ...
        </Configuration>
        <Configuration
            Name="Release|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
    ...
        </Configuration>
    </Configurations>
    <References>
        <AssemblyReference
            RelativePath="System.dll"
            AssemblyName="System, Version=2.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
            MinFrameworkVersion="131072"
        />
        <ProjectReference
            ReferencedProjectIdentifier="{7B000E40-727B-4E26-90F2-A437EA14F0D8}"
            UseDependenciesInBuild="false"
            RelativePathToProject=".\basics\proj001.vcproj"
        />
....
    </References>
    <Files>
    ...
    </Files>
    <Globals>
    </Globals>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

The files are based on the XML schema defined [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4sy8216%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). According to this scheme, the XML property "condition" is not defined.

Is there another way to set conditions (debug/release config, but also others) to references?

Comment: Right, this can't work on old versions of VS.  It is also rather incompatible with the IDE in general so finding another solution is rather strongly advisable.  Of course you can't get an answer if you don't explain why you think you need to do this.